# Removing multiple substrings in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column of ingredients in a pandas dataframe. I need to remove everything except the name of the ingredient (ex: 1/3 cup cashews > cashews).

**Input**

```
    recipe_name                                ingredient
0   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    ⅓ cup cashews
1   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    4 dates
2   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    1 tablespoon almond butter
3   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    3 tablespoons coconut milk
4   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    ½ teaspoon vanilla extract
```

**Expected Output**

```
    recipe_name                                ingredient
0   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    cashews
1   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    dates
2   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    almond butter
3   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    coconut milk
4   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    vanilla extract
```

I've tried using a dictionary, with common words mapped to empty strings like so:

```
remove_list ={'\d+': '', 'ounces': '', 'ounce': '', 'tablespoons': '', 'tablespoon': '', 'teaspoons': '', 'teaspoon': '', 'cup': '', 'cups': ''}
column = df['ingredient']
column.apply(lambda column: [remove_list[y] if y in remove_list else y for y in column])
```

This didn't change the data at all.

I've also tried using regex:

```
df['ingredients'] = re.sub(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, remove_list)), '', df['ingredients'])
```

But that just gives an error saying "TypeError: expected string or buffer."

I'm very new to Python so I think it's possible with regex, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to replace everything with the same character, just put them into a list.

```
l = ['\d+', '[^\x00-\x80]+', 'ounces', 'ounce', 'tablespoons', 
     'tablespoon', 'teaspoons', 'teaspoon', 'cup', 'cups']
```

Then use one `replace`, joining everything.

```
df.ingredient.str.replace('|'.join(l), '', regex=True).str.strip()
# Safer to only replace stand-alone words. strip not needed
#df.ingredient.str.replace('|'.join([x + '\s' for x in l]), '', regex=True)
```

#### Output:

```
0            cashews
1              dates
2      almond butter
3       coconut milk
4    vanilla extract
Name: ingredient, dtype: object
```

I added `'[^\x00-\x80]+'` to the list to remove those fractional characters, and the `.str.strip` removes any excess or leading whitespace after the replacements.

Comment: @Conor Just be careful, because this will accidentally replace something like `5 cupcakes`  with just `cakes`. You can get around that by making your replacements `'\cup\s'` that way it only replaces the word when followed by a space as in `'cup '` and not `'cupc'`

Comment: Ah thank you, I just checked back because I was having that problem.

Comment: @ALollz how can I amend it so that it will only replace the word when followed by nothing, i.e. end of string?

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of string functions built into pandas dataframes for this.

Something like this should work:

```
df['ingredient'] = df['ingredient'].str.replace('\d+', '', regex=True)
```

I don't know if you can use a dict with it, you may have to iterate through your dictionary to get all of the replacements that you want.

```
for ptn, rpl in remove_list.items():
    df['ingredient'] = df['ingredient'].str.replace(ptn, rpl, regex=True)
```

Comment: I was trying to do this without using an individual replace statement for every word but that may be the only way

Comment: You can use the dict that you've got to iterate through the patterns with just one extra line of code (as above).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop and the `.split()` method:

```
i = 0
for row in df['ingredient']:
    item = row.split(sep=' ', maxsplit=1)
    df['ingredient'].loc[i] = item[1]
    i += 1
```

The output will be:

```
    recipe_name                                ingredient
0   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    cup cashews
1   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    dates
2   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    tablespoon almond butter
3   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    tablespoons coconut milk
4   Truvani Chocolate Turmeric Caramel Cups    teaspoon vanilla extract
```

If you want to keep the measurements you can create a duplicate column and in one column keep the values and in the other keep the ingredient.